# Prove if $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, $\angle OBA = \angle ADO \iff \angle BOC = \angle AOD$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

The following is a lemma someone has presented to me:

> **Lemma:** 
>   Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram in the plane, and let $O$ be a point outside of the parallelogram.
>   Prove $\angle OBA = \angle ADO$ if and only $\angle BOC = \angle AOD$, where all angles are directed.

For example, here is a diagram: [image]

However, my attempts to find the proof and name, if one exists, of this lemma have not been successful. I have tried my hand at proving this myself, but I’m not all the best at geometry, so I didn’t make much progress.

Here’s a sketch of what I did:

I considered the isogonal conjugation of the points $A$ and $C$ with respect to triangle $OBD$. If we assume $\angle OBA = \angle ADO$, then both conjugates lie on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$, and if $\angle BOC = \angle AOD$, then the isogonal conjugate of $A$, $A^*$, lies on $OC$, and vice versa. However this method falls apart as it doesn’t encode the fact that $AB \parallel CD$ in a neat way.

Any hints or input will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is correct? My first drawing shows that it is not.

Comment: The statement is definitely not correct. The following could be true: $\angle OBA = \angle ADO \leftrightarrow \angle BDC = \angle AOD$. That one is trivial to prove.

Comment: @Oldboy: Whoops, diagram dependency. I have edited it to a more correct statement, taking directed angles instead. This means that $O$ cannot not lie on the circumcircle of $ABD$, which if $O$ were on, would indeed imply your observation.

Comment: So your parallelogram goes like ABDC, not ABCD.

Comment: No, the parallelogram is labelled ABCD. I will try to import an image.

Comment: Got it, finally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Let $A', C'$ be the reflections of $A$ and $C$ with respect to $OD, OB$, respectively. Let $Y, Z$ be the midpoints of $CC', AA'$, respectively. Note that $Y, Z$ are the perpendicular projections of $C, A$ onto $OB, OD$, repsectively.

You can prove that $\angle BOC = \angle AOD \iff \triangle AOC' \equiv \triangle A'OC \iff AC' = A'C \iff XY=XZ.$

Now, construct a parallelogram $AOCO'$ and note that $\angle ODA = \angle O'BC$. This is equivalent to $\angle OBC = \angle ABO'$. Let $T$ be the projection of $A$ onto $O'B$. Repeat the argument above to show the equivalence $\angle OBC = \angle ABO' \iff XY = XT$. Combine all ingredients keeping in mind that $XT=XZ$ due to symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

Translate $O$ for vector $AB$ to $O'$. Then $\angle BCO' = \angle ADO$ and $\angle BO'C = \angle AOD$.

[image]

Then $\angle AOD = \angle BOC \iff \angle BO'C = \angle BOC$ and that is iff $OO'BC$ is cyclic and that is iff $\angle BCO' = \angle BOO' = \angle OBA$ (since $AB||OO'$).

This is the end of a prove.